Update Specific field Cloud Build Trigger
I have hundreds of Cloud Build triggers using Gen1 source and the global location across multiple GCP projects, and I want to migrate them to Gen2 of the source. I tried using a Python script, similar to what I did to link the Cloud Build Repository to Gen2. However, I am still trying to find the best gcloud CLI command to update specific fields. In my case, I need to change the location to a specific region, switch from Gen1 to Gen2 source, and choose the repository.
this field

and this

I've reviewed the documentation at https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/builds/triggers several times, but the many options available still confuse me regarding which one is the right choice for my case.
I tried running the following command to make sure I can change the source of repository first before change the location :
gcloud builds triggers update bitbucket-cloud my-trigger --repository=projects/my-project/locations/us-west1/connections/my-conn/repositories/my-repo

But I received this error:
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.triggers.update.bitbucket-cloud) INVALID_ARGUMENT: cannot set more than one trigger config


Can you share your cloudbuild.yaml file? Also the Documentation you are following to migrate from Gen1 to Gen2? Basically the INVALID_ARGUMENT will be seen if the source may not exist, or the user may not have access to the source depending on the selected source type in build configuration.

what do you mean share cloudbuild.yaml ? I just want to modify existing trigger, change the location and source of repository.

I decided to use 3 commands

describe and load to json

result = subprocess.run(
                ['gcloud', 'builds', 'triggers', 'describe', trigger_name, '--format=json'],
                check=True,
                capture_output=True,
                text=True
            )
trigger = json.loads(result.stdout)


delete existing trigger

subprocess.run(
                ['gcloud', 'builds', 'triggers', 'delete', trigger['name'], '--project', gcp_project_id, '--quiet'])


create new one

subprocess.run([
                'gcloud', 'builds', 'triggers', 'create', 'bitbucket-cloud',
                '--name=' + trigger['name'],
                '--region=us-west1',
                '--repository=' + f'projects/{gcp_project_id}/'
                                  f'locations/{location}/'
                                  f'connections/bitbucket-connection-name/'
                                  f'repositories/{repo_name}',
                '--branch-pattern=' + trigger['triggerTemplate']['branchName'],
                '--build-config=' + trigger['filename'],
                '--project=' + gcp_project_id,
                '--substitutions=' + ",".join([f"{key}={value}" for key, value in trigger['substitutions'].items()])
            ])

I think this isn't a best way, (Did I miss something?) I hope GCP cloud build team provide a simple gcloud cli to update Cloud Build Trigger with specific fields on the future, something like
gcloud builds triggers update TRIGGER_NAME --region=us-west1 --gen=gen2 --repository=repository-name

